# Style Data Binding with assigned Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, styles

I want to create a `Style` as a Window Resource and that style requires to bind to property in the assigned control. Below is the simplified example of it.

Creating a style for buttons and apply the `Background` color using that assigned button controls tag property.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TestingStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Tag}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

When I add a `Button` with a `Color` in its `Tag`, this style should apply that color to `Button`'s background. Is this something possible?

**EDIT**

Below is the actual XMAL code.

```
<Style x:Key="SeriesStyle" TargetType="Chart:ChartSeries">
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="PointMarkerTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Ellipse Width="7" Height="7" Fill="Lavender" Stroke="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SeriesColor}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: What is happening, is it just one working or is it crashing?

Comment: What is SeriesColor, is it a property of ChartSeries?? Because if that is the case then RelativeSource Self wont necessarily work. Check my answer below, add some things to it

Comment: @Heinrich: When I apply this style it doesn't do anything (Not crashing).

Comment: @Heinrich: SeriesColor is a property of ChartSeries.

Comment: Just on a side note you are calling: <Chart:ChartSeries Style={StaticResource SeriesStyle} ... />

Comment: @Heinrich: Yes correct, that's how I am assigning the style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do that however you will have to bind to RelativeSource, as well as possibly having to create a converter that converts the object to a color, this is because Tag stores an object not Color,
 below is an example of Adding a Relative Source.

```
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}}" />
```

Edit:
 
Assuming that Series Color is Property on ChartSeries use:

```
{Binding Path=SeriesColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Chart:ChartSeries}}}
```

Comment: Sounds like a solution but didn't work. May be I've made a mistake. Coud you please see the edit in the question? Thanks

Comment: Still not working (style not applying). Thanks for showing the direction.

Comment: Mhmmm another thought PointMarker is an UIElement in itself, no? So when you use the method above you are looking for Parent it finds the PointMarker, so try adding "Path=Parent.SeriesColor" change "AncestorType={x:Type Chart:PointMarker}", I am just fishing now I don't know what ChartSeries is so I am just going on what I expect the cases to be.

Comment: Sorry, still no luck. Thanks for sending me the direction. I'll look into it.

Comment: Oh that sucks :/ No worries :) Goodluck :)

Comment: Found the issue, I need Color to Brush converter. It works now. Thanks Heinrich.

Answer (score 1):

Try this maybe:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Tag}" />
```